# Query data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 table here :

```
+ _news : id, title, url, image // This table contents all data of news.

+ _block : bid, id // This table content id of news and bid

+ _block_cate : bid, title, url // This table content type of news : PHP, SQL, HTML
```

The data of each table will be like that :

```
+ _news : id, title, url, image
          1   title1 url1 image1
          2   title2 url2 image2

+ _block : bid, id // id here is if of news.
            1   1
            2   1
            1   3

+ _block_cate : bid, title, url // This table contents data of each type.
                 1   PHP    php
                 2   SQL    SQL
                 3   HTML   html
```

I try to print to my homepage a result like that :

- News (1) - Title
- Type : PHP,SQL
- News (2) - Title 2
- Type : HTML

I tried 2 level query but it not work.
Any idea for this query ?

// You can also check the demo here
http://blogtruyen.com/trangchu
I am trying to make a webpage like that. Each Manga show theirown info and also the type it belongs to.
I hope someone can give me an advise.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear from your question what you need.I think you need it like this.

```
select NW.title,* from _news NW
left join _block BK ON NW.id=BK.id
left join _block_cate BC ON BK.bid = BC.bid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `n`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(`bc`.`title`) `titles`
FROM `news` `n`
LEFT JOIN `block` `b` ON `n`.`id` = `b`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `block_cate` `bc` ON `b`.`bid` = `bc`.`bid`
GROUP BY `n`.`id`
```

This should work for you.